# SATA II drive compatibility with Dell e6400 laptop

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I've got a [Dell e6400 laptop](http://www.dell.com/us/en/business/notebooks/laptop_latitude_e6400/pd.aspx?refid=laptop_latitude_e6400&cs=04&s=bsd). Would a SATA II drive be compatible?

Answer (score 1):

in a word, yes.

SATA II drives are backwards compatible.

*[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SATA#Backward_and_forward_compatibility)*

Comment: ok, thanks
Would the SATA II version of the same drive perform any better in my e6400?

Comment: no, if your controller only supports 150 MB/s, then that's it.